# How to identify and delete Linux Bootloader/GRUB from my HDD?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, ssd, grub

Im using win 10 in my principal HDD.

I needed a dual boot with linux mint, which should be in my SSD, so I installed it. The problem is that it installed the BOOTLOADER in the EFI of my HDD and not in the SSD as I specify in the installer.

Now, reinstalling Linux so it just has its own EFI in the SSD, I need to IDENTIFY and delete the OLD bootloader which was installed in my HDD. I do not know how to identify it.

Here is a img of my diskpart volumes, SSD is not appearing because I just cleaned it.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the EFI partition is that many tools won't allow to
delete it.

You may use diskpart (or other tools) to change
EFI system partition ID (type) and set it as a data partition.
This gives you later the option to manipulate it using a
partition editor, while keeping the option
of undoing the change in case you encounter a problem.

Here is how to do that with diskpart :

- Run diskpart
- `list disk` to displays all disks
- `sel disk X`
- `list partition` to display all partitions
- `sel partition Y` for the EFI partition
- `SET ID=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7`

This will make the EFI system partition deletable with the normal
disk tools later on.

To undo this change, set its ID back to
`C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B`.

The above advice is for GPT disks. For MBR disks, the ID is `0xEF`.

Comment: Thanks but this does not solve my problem. I'm particulary interested on identify the partition better than delete it, I don't wanna throw my entire Windows away by deleting a wrong partition.

Comment: The UEFI searches all disks for an EFI partition and boots from the first one that it finds, by disk number. It identifies the partition by its ID. I don't think the risk is large, since the EFI partition works on the SSD. But I'm not physically before your computer, so cannot ever be 100% sure of my advice.

Comment: And there is no partition letter for the EFI partition.

Comment: @wido: Did you downvote my answer?